# EF attaching object to context in foreach working only first time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have a list of objects that I need to attach to the Context in order to track changes and, afterward, saving them, but the foreach iterating the items executes only the first time, after that the method ends.
I'm certain that those items already exist in the database.

I have tried both calling the `.Attach()` method and setting the Entry state to Unchanged.

```cs
protected override Task SetViewModelPropertiesAsync()
        {

            SelectedItems.ForEach(l =>
            {
                //Context.Pap_Pedido_ODP.Attach(l);
                Context.Entry(l).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
                // After the first iteration the method ends
            });


            return base.SetViewModelPropertiesAsync();
        }
```

I expect all the items to be added to context but after the first iteration of the foreach loop breaks the method and continues to the next one, without even giving an exception.

EDIT:
There is more code after the foreach that is being skipped when I do either the Attach or EntityState.
If I comment both the code executes correctly

Comment: Maybe there's only one item in the collection.

Comment: Most likely the item has a primary key so it only gets added once.

Comment: @Bigabdoul No, I know there are, at least, 2 items and I have debugged to check it

Comment: @jdweng Each of the items has it's own primary key, but the frightening thing is that the **entire method** breaks. There is more code after the foreach (that I have not included in the question example) and it's being skipped

Comment: I've seen problems like this.  After spending time stepping through the code I usually find an exception.  It seems the c# when it finds an exception with no exception handler it moves up the execution stack and finds first exception handler in a Ancestor method.  The exception handler could be any place in the Ancestor.  So when I step through the code after the exception it goes to the parent method and then does a crazy jump to an exception handler that is in another section of code.  To fix I add a new exception handler.

Comment: @jdweng this seems to be correct, but it's strange because I've checked the ancestors and I haven't found exception handlers.

Comment: You are overriding the SetViewModelPropertiesAsync class which is in your code (not a net library method).  Add exception handle in that base method.

Comment: @jdweng I can't do that. This is a work project and the parent clases can only be modified by the boss. I have handled it inside the foreach and seems to work, the first item was already in the context.

Comment: Explain to your boss if the exception is jumping to an exception handler in the code you can't capture the exception.  You only other choice is find the what is causing the exception and fix it before you call the base method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour does sound like an exception is being thrown. This is IMO a huge red-flag about `List<T>.ForEach()` and the main reason I never use it. If you alter your code to:

```
foreach(var item in SelectedItems)
{
   Context.Pap_Pedido_ODP.Attach(item);
   Context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged;
}
```

... you should at least now see the exception(s) that are blocking your code. Attaching/Detaching entities between contexts is messy and there are very, very few scenarios where I personally can ever justify it. You are dealing with references to an entity. This means that:

1. item must not already be associated to any other context.
2. Context must not already have another entity tracked with the same PK as item.

Point #1 will hinder you because any code returning an entity that "might" want to attach that entity to another context will need to detach, or otherwise load that entity AsNoTracking. Passing a tracked entity to your method from somewhere will break your code.

Point #2 will hinder you because even if the entity passed is detached, if your context happens to already know about that entity via another reference, you have to essentially discard that untracked entity, and use the reference to the tracked instance. This means before attaching any entity you need to check Context .Local for a matching entity.

Only if the entity isn't tracked, and the context does not have a tracked entity with the same PK can you attach it.

If your code is not breaking on an exception and you are debugging, make sure your debug exception handling is set to break on all exceptions. Alternatively you can pop a try/catch block with a breakpoint in the catch to inspect the exception.

Edit: To check instances

```
foreach(var item in SelectedItems)
{
   if(Context.Pap_Pedido_ODP.Local.Contains(item))
   { // This exact instance is already associated to the Context.
     // We shouldn't need to copy anything across or do anything...
   }
   else
   {
      var existingItem = Context.Pap_Pedido_ODP.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id);
      if(existingItem != null)
      { // A different instance matching this one already exists in the context, 
        // Here if item represents changes we would need to copy changes across to existingItem...
      }
      else
      { // Item is not associated, safe to attach.
          Context.Pap_Pedido_ODP.Attach(item);
          // ...
      }
   }
}
```

Now it doesn't end there. If "item" contains references to other entities, each and every one will be updated automatically. This can cause problems if some of them have already been associated to the context. This can be caused when the DbContext is too long-lived or where multiple copies of the same instance of a referenced entity are passed back. For instance if I have a set of Orders being saved, and Orders contain references to Customers. 2 orders have a reference to the same customer.  When I attach Order #1 to Customer #1, Customer 1 is now associated to the context. When I try to attach Order #2, the instance of Customer #1 is a different instance to Order #1 so attaching Order #2 will generate an error.  When dealing with detached entities, you need to take steps to ensure that *all* instances of objects in the graph that refer to the same record are using the same object instance reference. When you loaded the data from EF, these would be the same object reference, but if you feed them to a Serializer/Deserializer you will get 2 identical copies as separate references. You cannot simply re-attach those object references.

Unfortunately there's no really simple answer I can offer to make it easier, but this is why serializing and deserializing entities can be a terrible idea, and even detaching/attaching instances can be a pain.

Comment: As you said, changing ```List<T>.ForEach()``` threw the exception causing the problem.
But I don't know why it is being thrown, If I don't attach it when I call ```Context.SaveChanges()``` I get another exception saying that there are elements that are not in the context, but If I add attach them, I get another exception saying the element is already in the Context.

Comment: This will be likely a combination of attached and unattached references. If object A has references to instances of B and each B has references to instances of C, each instance down the chain needs to be checked against the context. Attaching and Detaching object graphs are a messy, messy thing.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to cover off some things to watch out for when attaching entities.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently this is the problem, I have checked in ```Local``` the asociated entities and there it was. I have ended up passing the Id's and querying them to get them attached.

Comment: Yep. It can look like re-attaching is a good option to save time since the data was already loaded at one point, but it's far more trouble than it's worth. Loading entities by ID is fast, detached entities can be problematic to re-attach as you've seen, and detached entities may be stale between when they were originally read and when you go to update them. (someone else edited the data) It has a place, but should not be a default design for persistence.